# Node build command not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using this config in package.json file for running webpack dev server. I want to use a build command as well, but its not working for me

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack --watch"
},
```

`npm start` command works fine, but build isn't

Comment: See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start vs https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will have to use `npm run build` because `build` is an internal built in keyword (see docs here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build).

Therefore:

```
npm build // refers to built in
```

and..

```
npm run build // refers to your script
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation about built in and script

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use this:

```
   npm run build
```